# Hacer un constructor sincrono JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Quiero hacer que no se pueda ejecutar ninguna función de una clase hasta que no haya terminado de ejecutarse el constructor.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const axios = require('axios');

class GetPrices {
    constructor(token_address, lp_address) {
        this.web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "https://bsc-dataseed2.binance.org");
        this.contracts = {}
        this.addresses = {
            "token": token_address,
            "lp": lp_address,
            "bnb": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
            "busd": "0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56",
            "bnbbusd": "0x1B96B92314C44b159149f7E0303511fB2Fc4774f",
        }

        for (const address in this.addresses){
            this.getContract(address, this.addresses[address])
        }
    }

    getContract(name, address) {
        let res = axios.get(`https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${address}`).then((res) => {
            let abi = res.data.result
            this.contracts[name] = new this.web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), this.addresses[this.addresses])
        })
        
    }

    async getPrices(){
        let amounts = await Promise.all([
            await this.contracts['busd'].methods.balanceOf(this.addresses['bnbbusd']).call(),
            await this.contracts['bnb'].methods.balanceOf(this.addresses['bnbbusd']).call(),
            await this.contracts['bnb'].methods.balanceOf(this.addresses['lp']).call(),
            await this.contracts['token'].methods.balanceOf(this.addresses['lp']).call(),
        ])
        let bnbbusd_price = amounts[0] / amounts[1]
        let tokenbnb_price = (amounts[2]/10**18) / (amounts[3]/10**this.token_decimals)
        let tokenbusd_price = bnbbusd_price * tokenbnb_price
        return [tokenbnb_price, tokenbusd_price]
    }

    async getTotalSupply(){
        return await this.contracts['token'].methods.totalSupply().call() / 10**this.token_decimals
    }
}

prices = new GetPrices('0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82', '0xA527a61703D82139F8a06Bc30097cC9CAA2df5A6')
console.log(prices.getPrices())
```

El problema es que para ejecutar la función getPrices() necesito que el constructor haya terminado su ejecución, de lo contrario this.contracts esta vacía y da error.

Comment: Siempre puedes crear una variable de control, lo inicializas a false, cuando haya cargado del todo lo pones a true, y cuando se llame una función, que espere a que sea true o devuelva un error si no lo hace en un tiempo prudencial....

Comment: puedes sacar la logica de obtener los contratos fuera del constuctor. Y hacer `const prices = new GetPrices(); await prices.getContract(); await prices.getPrices()`. Tendras que usar async/awwait en `getContract`

Comment: No apliques lógica en el constructor, no es una buena práctica. En vez de eso, carga la data bajo demanda o mejor inyéctala al objeto. Lo que tratas de hacer no es práctico, para eso mejor usas programación imperativa y no declarativa. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En otros lenguajes de programación es normal crear un constructor privado y usar una función generadora para crear instancias. En Javascript no puedes marcar como privado el constructor, pero sí puedes crear un método estático en la clase que sirva como generador e indicar en la documentación (si va a ser usado por otros desarrolladores) que el constructor no debería usarse directamente.

```js
class Example {
  /**
  * No usar, llamar a getInstance
  */
  constructor() {}
   
  static async getInstance(id) {
    const instance = new Example();
    instance.data = await Example.getResource(id);
    return instance;
  }
  
  static async getResource(pokeId) {
    const data = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeId}`);
    return data.json();
  }
  
}

const examplePromise = Example.getInstance(1);
examplePromise.then(exampleInstance => {
  console.log("Ya tengo mi instancia rellena con", exampleInstance.data.name);
});
```

Puesto que getInstance no se completa hasta que las llamadas asíncronas no se han completado, no podrás usar una instancia a medio crear/rellenar.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que la función `constructor` no puede ser `async`, hay que crear un alternativo así:

```js
class Foo {
  async constructorAsync() {
    return this;
  }
}

new Foo().constructorAsync().then(console.log);
```